# How can I parse a .txt with a delimiter that has multiple characters into a pandas df?

Tags: python, regex, pandas, separator

I have a *large* dataset that I'd like to analyse in python with pandas. It's all contained in a .txt but the separator is +++$+++. How can I parse this?

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('filename.txt', sep='+++$+++', header=None)
```

These two lines bring up this error:

```
sre_constants.error: nothing to repeat
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

that's because if the separator is longer than 1 char it's interpreted as a regular expression, as stated in http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html; so the + indicat "any number of matches of the before char", which there isn't, so there's "nothing to repeat".

i think escaping the symbols might work.

Comment: Good point! I'd also add an example - this might help someone... `import re; df = pd.read_csv(r'/path/to/file.csv'. sep=re.escape('+++$+++'))`

Comment: In other words, `\+{3}\$\+{3}`

Answer (score 3):

Although it is late to answer. I faced the same query today. My solution for this is:

`pd.read_table('test.txt',header=None,sep=' \+\+\+\$\+\+\+ ', engine='python')`

This works perfectly.